# Exception constructor overloading

Tags: c#, inheritance, exception

When creating a custom `Exception` type in C#, why is it considered to be good practice to overload all of those constructors:

```
Exception()
Exception(String)
Exception(String, Exception)
```

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#include-three-constructors-in-custom-exception-classes

I see no given reason for that in any of those recommendations.

If I want to create a custom `Exception` which shall be thrown if an unknown error occurs calling another system, why is it considered to be good to overwrite the other constructors here, if I just need information about the failed system and the operation that lead to it:

```
public class ExternalSystemCallException : Exception {
    public string FailedSystem { get; }
    public string OperationName { get; }

    public ExternalSystemCallFailedException(string failedSystem, string operationName) {
        FailedSystem = failedSystem;
        OperationName = operationName;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I know there could be other information I could pass here, so this is just a rather simple example.

**UPDATE 1:**

So as I understand it, I shall overwrite all constructors but add all of the parameters the Exception needs additionally as well. Is that correct?

Example:

```
Exception(string failedSystem, string operationName) 
    : base()

Exception(string failedSystem, string operationName, string message) 
    : base(message)

Exception(string failedSystem, string operationName, string message, Exception innerException) 
    : base(message, innerException)
```

Comment: Because the developers that want to raise your exception *expect* your class to have them and behave properly. `Exception.Message` *must* contain a message explaining what's wrong. Quite often, that's the only thing that gets logged or reported in SO questions. Your class though would return an empty string. Exceptions *can* be nested, in fact custom exceptions typically *wrap* other exceptions. Your `ExternalSystemCallException` was probably raised in response to some other exception. Users, support people, and *you* in the future will want to know what that was

Comment: The best practices describes a generalisation of the pattern for reuse by other developers and within the system. Your example describes a specific use case and therefore will not fit the practice.

The best practices are for scenarios that describe: 1. A default throw without information. 2. A throw with a custom message. 3 A throw with an innerexception and a custom message.

Comment: `Exception()` - exception ocurred, `Exception(String)` exception with *message*, `Exception(String, Exception)` exception with *message* and *inner cause*.

Comment: BTW unless you override `ToString()`, `FailedSystem` and `OperationName` will not appear in logs or messages. Format strings and calls to `ToString()` will end up calling `Exception.ToString()` which returns the `Message`, all inner exceptions and the call stack. You need to set the message in your constructors if you want to see the properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because both `Message` and `InnerException` properties are readonly on `Exception` class. That means the only way to set them is via constructor. Your implementation does not allow to set those properties, because you omit related constructors. That means your exception:

1. Loses valuable information contained in another exception which lead to it (if any). It's InnerException is always null.
2. Display no human readable information when logged or displayed to user. When exception is logged - only properties of base `Exception` class are taken into account, such as `Message` and `InnerException`. Those properties are always null for your exception, so only stack trace (and even that is not complete) will appear in log (your `FailedSystem` and `OperationName` will not appear there too).

You might think that users of your code will catch specific `ExternalSystemCallException` exception and then act based on its properties, but that's not what often happens. Your code might be used as a part of larger operation, then there will be some catch-all handler up the stack which will just log exception and show some error message to the user. So having base `Exception` properties set to meaningful values is imporatant.

To "fix" your exception type you might consider doing something like this:

```
public class ExternalSystemCallException : Exception
{
    public string FailedSystem { get; }
    public string OperationName { get; }

    public ExternalSystemCallException(
             string failedSystem, 
             string operationName, 
             Exception innerException = null)
            : base($"Operation {operationName} failed in {failedSystem}", innerException) {
        FailedSystem = failedSystem;
        OperationName = operationName;
    }        
}
```

That way you always set `Message` to meaningful value and allow to pass `InnerException` if needed. Empty `Exception` constructor can be omited if it never makes sense to throw exception of your type without providing system and operation name values.

Comment: Considering logging: is there a mechanism to make `FailedSystem` and `OperationName` properties being logged as well?

Comment: @SebastianKrogull I've updated answer with suggestion.

Comment: @SebastianKrogull in your case you can construct message yourself from information passed to constructor (like in example in this answer), so there is no reason to also accept "message" parameter.